# Действительно ли C/C++ сначала компилируется в ассемблер?

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер, gcc

Часто вижу, что процесс компиляции описывают примерно так: сорс -> ассемблер -> объектный файл -> бинарный файл. Но в том же gcc для получения ассемблера надо указать дополнительный флаг, а объектный файл в любом случае будет. Правда ли, что этот флаг выполняет другую (отдельную) процедуру, а не просто останавливает этот конвейер на втором шаге? Т.е. действительно ли C/С++ код компилируется в ассемблер, а после этого в байткод? Или ассемблера вообще может не быть в процессе генерации бинаря, если не указать флаг?

P.S.: вопрос не про стандарт (с его т.з. может быть что угодно), а про реальные компиляторы (gcc, clang, msvc).

Comment: [Do programming language compilers first translate to assembly or directly to machine code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845355/do-programming-language-compilers-first-translate-to-assembly-or-directly-to-mac#:~:text=GCC%20compiles%20to%20assembler.)

Comment: В реальных сценариях кодогенерация происходит только на последнем шаге, при создании бинаря. Собственно можете для проверки поглядеть, что хранится в объектных файлах.

Comment: @user7860670 хотите сказать, что в объектных файлах не бинарный код с незарезолвленными адресами, а текст?

Comment: Я не думаю, что там текст, скорее какое-то промежуточное представление.

Comment: Если у вас один и тот же код на разных языках, то  результат работы компиляторов приведут к одному и тому же ассемблеру, а бинарный код получается на его основе. А объектный файл это   таблица(текст)  промежуточный процесс

Comment: @ARHovsepyan вопрос в том, действительно ли компиляторы генерят ассемблер, а на его основе - бинарный код. Или обходятся без ассемблера, а дают его отдельно при явном запросе?

Comment: Я думал вы поймете намек _ а как же без этого, если компилятор предназначен именно для этого. Просто он может быть представлен а может нет. Не понятно что не понятно

Comment: Убедиться своими глазами элементарно — `strace -f gcc -c test.c`

Comment: Кстати, clang (я проверял дебиановский 11й) работает в этом смысле иначе, чем gcc.

Answer (score 1):

`gcc` сначала делает ассемблер, а потом с помощью `as` получает из него машинный код. `clang` и `msvc` сразу получают машинный код без промежуточного ассемблера.

Comment: clang транслирует в ассемблер LLVM, msvc в ассемблер

Answer (score -3):

Начать нужно с основ. Есть два вида программ: в машинных кодах (бинарник, исполняемый файл и пр.) и не в машинных кодах. Программу в машинных кодах исполняет непосредственно процессор. Программу не в машинных кодах исполняет интерпретатор, или иная исполняющая система, которая сама является программой в машинных кодах (либо ещё одним интерпретатором, но в конце концов всё доходит до машинных кодов).

Изначально компиляцией называлось преобразование программы в машинных код. Сейчас к этому добавилось преобразование в байт-код или промежуточный код, который потом выполняется интерпретатором. Компилятор, как правило, использует промежуточные т. н. объектные файлы. Это связано исключительно с многомодульностью и использованием каких-либо библиотек.

Программа на ассеблере тоже компилируется в машинный код с использованием объектных файлов.

Примеры интерпретаторов: Питон, Руби, Ява-машина и пр. Обозреватель Интернета тоже является интерпретатором языка HTML и каких-то скриптовых языков. Может, при необходимости, подключать внешние интерпретаторы. Сам может быть как программой в машинных кодах, так и какой-то интерпретируемой программой.

Что касается компилятора C++. Генерация ассемблерного текста там - просто дополнительная опция.

И так, по пунктам:

1. "Часто вижу, что процесс компиляции описывают примерно так: сорс -> ассемблер -> объектный файл -> бинарный файл" - Очевидно, это верно для языка C и компилятора gcc. Но для других компиляторов это может быть не так, ассемблер не является обязательным в этой цепочке.
2. "Но в том же gcc для получения ассемблера надо указать дополнительный флаг, а объектный файл в любом случае будет" - похоже, что в качестве промежуточного языка согласно модели компилятора для C и gcc используется именно ассемблер.
3. "Правда ли, что этот флаг выполняет другую (отдельную) процедуру, а не просто останавливает этот конвейер на втором шаге?" - нет.
4. "Т.е. действительно ли C/С++ код компилируется в ассемблер, а после этого в байткод?" - для C и gcc да, но только не в байткод, а в машинный код.
5. "вопрос не про стандарт (с его т.з. может быть что угодно), а про реальные компиляторы (gcc, clang, msvc)" - с другими компиляторами по-другому, как уже написали в комментариях.

Кстати, обратите вннимание, что assembler в буквальном переводе означает сборщик, то есть ассемблер - это язык для сборочных файлов. Скорее всего, когда-то так родилось, и с тех пор всё ещё используется в некоторых случаях. Большой проект мог быть написан на различных языках, потом он транслировался в ассемблер и потом собирался. А сейчас и памяти побольше, и дискового пространства, и технологии обработки информации усовершенствовались.

Comment: Реальный gcc (по крайней мере еще лет 10 назад) в ходе компиляции пишет ассемблер в .s и далее вызывает  asm (а опция -S просто останавливает процесс в точке создения .s)

Comment: Кроме последнего предложения все не о том, что автор спрашивал.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja как раз о том. Из вопроса видно, что автор, скорее всего, плохо понимает, о чём справшивает. А если бы он понимал тему, то искал бы ответ в другом месте.

Comment: @avp Очевидно, это особенность конкретного компилятора. Возможно, (некоторые) другие реализованы аналогично. Мы же понимаем, что ассемблер там совсем не нужен в качестве промежуточного языка. Скорее, это возможность для низкоуровневого программирования, анализа или чего-то подобного. Компилятор может использовать ассемблер, по ключу в командной строке выдавать текст в отдельный файл(ы).

Comment: А вы почитайте вопрос. Он про особенности конкретных компиляторов.

Comment: @rotabor, imho автор вопроса все понимает (только очень многословно сформулировал свой вопрос), а вот вы (по крайней мере по отношению к gcc) ответили на него (в последнем абзаце) неверно

Comment: @user_587 Ага, автор просто перечислил то, что ему на глаза попалось. Вопрос достаточно общий, а переход на контретику означает проблемы в формулировании вопроса.

Comment: @avp не думаю, что я неправ. Неохота рыться везде. Почитайте хотя бы https://www.quora.com/Does-GCC-generate-assembly-from-the-C-source-or-from-the-binary-code-it-compiled-into

Comment: @rotabor, мало ли, что в интернетах напишут... Я не поленился, вызвал сейчас `gcc -v ...` и убедился, что по прежнему он пишет в .s и потом вызывает asm